# How am I supposed to address elements that are not a direct child of a given element in CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Consider this snippet:

```
<div class="container">
  <input type="text">
  <div class="myList">
   <input type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

I thought the following selector could address entire text inputs, except for those that are direct child of myList which apparently I was wrong:

```
.container :not(div.myList) input[type="text"] {
}
```

How am I supposed to that? Is it possible in CSS? Here's the http://jsfiddle.net/C46tN/ I've created to make things faster.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this acceptable in real life? http://jsfiddle.net/C46tN/1/

Comment: @Passerby No, not really.

Comment: Which part is unacceptable?

Comment: I'm just having second thought. Let me try it on my real world usage & I'll tell you back. Thank you.

Comment: You should try specifying the styles for the higher level `<input>` element, and then override the styles for the nested `<input>` using `.mylist > input[type="text"]`.

Comment: The space is a descendant selector. It selects everything inside an element. If you're looking for the child selector that would be `>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 problems:

1) You can not do :not(div.myList). You can only do :not(.myList).

this is the correct syntax:

```
.container :not(.myList) input[type="text"] {
    border:2px solid #f00;
}
```

This is not a real problem if you set this class only to divs.

2) What you are really saying with this rule is: inouts that are descendants of an element that is not of class myList, that is descendatn of container. That means that you won't select direct descendants of container.